# day counter using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

if I  have a data set of time series and I want to estimate the number of the day of a groupby time series per each day as seen in the figure and act as a counter :

[image]

nothing special in my code yet, it is just reading the data and convert time and day into

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv('*file location and name*',sep=",")
df.head()
df['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+" "+df['Time'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if answers your query:

```
df['dayOfMonth']= df.groupby('day').cumcount() + 1
```

Comment: Worked PERFECTLY , thanks